# Conditional input with name attribute result to undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to add a condition to decide if I should show/hide `mybutton`, but keep getting a console error that mybutton is undefined when it evaluates `mybutton.disabled`

So, to test, I added a true statement that `1===1` but still throws the same error.

Why does it do that? What is the least way to refactor this, so I can add a condition here?

```
<div [ngSwitch]="item.id">
    <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="id1">
        <pv-my-selector (onSaveShow)="onSaveShow(mybutton, $event)"></pv-my-selector>
    </ng-template>
</div>
<button *ngIf="1===1" #mybutton mat-button (click)="saveClick(item.id)">Save</button>

onSaveShow(mybutton: any, show: boolean) {
    mybutton.disabled = !show; <!-- error is here -->
}

saveClick(id: string) {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below block is rendered before the button block and the `mybutton` is undefined here because it's not defined yet.

```
<div [ngSwitch]="item.id">
    <ng-template [ngSwitchCase]="id1">
        <pv-my-selector (onSaveShow)="onSaveShow(mybutton, $event)"></pv-my-selector>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

I suggest to use `ViewChild()` and import the button to your component:

```
@ViewChild('mybutton', {static: false}) mybutton;
```

And check if the button exists before making changes to it:

```
onSaveShow(show: boolean) {
    if (this.mybutton) {
      this.mybutton.disabled = !show;
    }
}
```

The alternative would be to use `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf`.

Comment: using [hidden]="1===1" didn't give me those errors when using *ngIf="1===1"